# Siunitx V3 on Overleaf

Tags: siunitx, overleaf

Does anybody know how or if one can use siunitx V3 on Overleaf? It seems that Overleaf only has TeX Live 2020 which does not include the newest siunitx.

Is there any way of getting around that?

Comment: Not sure, I do think they have tl21, but as far as I know they don't update packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overleaf only update after extensive testing. As such, as for any newer package, you'll need to add the file(s) to your project: in this case, you need a copy of (v3) `siunitx.sty`, which you can get if you have an up-to-date local install or from the ['ready to install' zip on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx.tds.zip).

Comment: Would v3 work with TL2020 binaries, expl3 etc.?

Comment: @yo' Yes, of course: minimal `expl3`: 2018-06-01

Comment: Ok great, thanks!

Comment: @yo' Essentially, `siunitx` uses only long-standing `expl3` ideas - the reason for the current version requirement is renames in `expl3` not new features. The one thing tht will impact there is when we (finally) have code-level interfaces for `\hfil` and `\kern`, but that's sill 'some way off'.