# Siunitx 3 on Overleaf with TeX Live 2020

Tags: siunitx, overleaf

This question is a follow-up on [Siunitx V3 on Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600489/siunitx-v3-on-overleaf).

I am trying to use version 3 of the siunitx package on Overleaf (TeX Live 2020). After adding the siunitx.sty, as recommended in the previous question, I get compilation errors associated with commands such as

```
\NewDocumentCommand \DeclareBinaryPrefix { +m m m }
```

in siunitx. The generated PDF also displays these lines on the top of the page :
[image]

I created a new Overleaf project, added the siunitx.sty file, and the main.tex file is simply

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This is a test : \qty{5}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

When removing the version 3 file and changing the \qty to \SI to accommodate the version 2 included in TeX Live 2020, everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

The specific problem that prevented v3.0.22 from compiling nicely with the older TeX Live 2020 on Overleaf was resolved in v3.0.23 (2021-07-26) of `siunitx`.

The code `siunitx` loading `xparse` if it is not yet in the kernel came in a tad too late for some `\NewDocumentCommand`s. See https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/518.

So grab version v3.0.23 or above from CTAN and you should be fine.

---

### Old answer

There is absolutely no guarantee that this will work, but the primary issue appears to be that `\NewDocumentCommand` is undefined. That command was recently-ish moved from the `xparse` package to the LaTeX kernel. In older systems you may have to load `\usepackage{xparse}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
This is a test: \qty{5}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

compiles for me. At least with the `siunitx.sty` available from `.tds.zip` from CTAN (http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx.tds.zip) (v3.0.22 from 2021-07-22).

See https://www.overleaf.com/read/mwpxvvhrjwvz.

Comment: `siunitx.sty` presumably takes this into consideration with: `\IfFormatAtLeastTF { 2020-10-01 } { } { \RequirePackage { xparse } }`. This doesn't mean I know why it fails for the OP and your MWE works... Does "recently-ish" means later than "2020-10-01"?

Comment: @gusbrs Oh, so it does. But too late (l. 7333) for some `\NewDocumentCommand`s (e.g. ll. 7090, 7094) in the `.sty`. Reported at https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/518.

Comment: And yes, `xparse` was added to the kernel in the October 2020 release.

Comment: Ah, great! That clears things up. And thanks for reporting!

Comment: Updated on CTAN. Version 3.0.23 solves the problem. Thanks for reporting!