# Siunitx 3 and amsmath : compilation time out on Overleaf with TeX Live 2020

Tags: amsmath, siunitx, overleaf, nicematrix

When using version 3.0.23 of `siunitx` on Overleaf with TeX Live 2020, I get compilation time out when running the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This is a test : \qty{5}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

Changing the order of the package loading doesn't change the end result.

Removing `amsmath` allows the file to compile normally, and so is reverting to `siunitx` 2.8 included in TeX Live 2020 on Overleaf while keeping `amsmath`. Also, in the packages I use daily, only `nicematrix` has the same time out problem, but it has `amsmath` as a required package.

Any chance someone here encountered that problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a log file? I have no issues using the frozen TL20 I have on disk with an added `siunitx` v3

Comment: You've manually installed v3? At present you'll need to force-load `xparse`: I've uploaded a fix for that, but it's not on CTAN just yet.

Comment: @JosephWright, the `xparse` problem is solved in 3.0.23 which is the one I used. I am the person who asked the question about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606350/siunitx-3-on-overleaf-with-tex-live-2020).

Comment: @JosephWright make sense as the frozen TL20 have xparse in the kernel but I don't think Overleaf uses the frozen version

Comment: @Zork Well I've checked with TL'20 with `siunitx` v3.0.23, and all is well. I'm going to need some kind of log to get further.

Comment: @JosephWright you can get a log if you stop compilation if you click on the compile button and choose "stop compilation", I managed to get a 50 MB log with tracingmacros. I can send you the part just before it starts to loop (imho it looks as if it gets in trouble at begin document)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I can see where the issue is coming from: homing in now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by a non-robust definition of `\,` with older set-ups, which means that there is an internal error when trying to expand and replace `\,` (needed internally for `input-ignore`). The easiest work-around it to make `\,` robust, for example

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\,
```

before loading `siunitx` v3.

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as a bug: I need to think about it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is relative to `nicematrix` since I'm the author of that package. A drawback of `nicematrix` is that it requires several compilations, with informations written on the `aux` file between the compilations (for use in the next run). As far as I know, Overleaf uses `latexmk` which does the compilations until the `aux` file has not changed between two compilations.

However, when Overleaf stops the cycle of compilations because of time-out, it does not delete the `aux` file and, usually, when a new cycle of compilations is required (by clicking on the corresponding button), the job is done even if you have had a time-out when cliking the first time...